# zen of Python vs with statement - philosophical pondering

Tags: python, coding-style, indentation, with-statement, zen-of-python

I don't intend to simply waste your time, but: **has it occurred to you too, while using Python's `with` statement that it really is contrary to the 5th line of "The Zen of Python" that goes "Flat is better than nested"? Can any enlightened Python guru share me some of their  insights on this?**

(I always find that one more level of indentation pops up in my code every time I use `with` instead of `f.close()`... and it's not like I'm not gonna use `try: ... finally: ...` anyways and thus the benefits of `with` still elude me, even as I grow to like and understand Python more and more...)

---

@glglgl (sorry, I can't find a way to write code in comments):
yes, but if you go the `with` way, your code becomes:

```
try:
    with file(...) as f:
        ...
except IOError:
    ...
```

...and using just with without the `try` is what people end up doing in the type of hacky "one use" code where they use `f.close()` instead of with anyways (which is bad because the file may not be closed if an exception is thrown before their `f.close()`), so for "hacky" code people just don't use `with` because, I don't know, I guess they just find it too "fancy" and for well structured code it doesn't bring any benefits anyways, so it seems to me there's no real world use case left for it... that was my pondering about really.

Comment: Most of the time I just let IOError propagate and catch it somewhere else.

Comment: As much as I disagree with the premise of this question, I have to give you props for making me go back and re-read PEPs [342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) and [343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states "Flat is better than nested", however it is not the only characteristic we care about; it also states "Simple is better than complex". The beauty of `with` is that it actually adheres to **both** of those principles as I will explain below.

Any time you find yourself in philosophical pondering about a feature in Python it's probably worth looking up the [Python Enhancement Proposals (PEPs)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/) to read about the motivation behind the feature. In this case [PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) says it up front in the abstract:

> This PEP adds a new statement "with" to the Python language to make it
>   possible to factor out standard uses of try/finally statements.

Factoring out `try/finally` statements makes the code simpler and more readable.

[PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) goes deeper than providing some simplistic syntactic sugar, however. It establishes a context manager protocol:

> The expression immediately following the with keyword in the statement
>   is a "context expression" as that expression provides the main clue as
>   to the runtime environment the context manager establishes for the
>   duration of the statement body.

Using the context manager protocol, API writers can help hide complexity and ensure correct acquisition/release of resources in a multi-threaded context.

But the real beauty of the `with` statement is shown in Example 12 of [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) which explains that:

> A "nested" context manager that automatically nests the supplied
>   contexts from left-to-right to avoid excessive indentation.

Using the `nested()` context manager you can take code that looks like this:

```
with a as x:
    with b as y:
        with c as z:
            # Perform operation
```

and turn it into this:

```
with nested(a, b, c) as (x, y, z):
             # Perform operation
```

Note that `nested()` was introduced in Python 2.5, but as of version 2.7 it is deprecated in favor of this multiple context manager syntactic form:

```
with a as x, b as y, c as z:
             # Perform operation
```

Clearly not only is this simpler and more readable, but it is much more flat than nested. Thus, using `with` is following the path of [無爲](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei) :)

**UPDATE:** In response to [comments on Simeon Visser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373733/462302) here is an example of when you might use multiple context managers to open more than one file at once, when you want to zip the contents of two (or more) files together such that if opening one of the files fails it will make the whole thing fail and properly close each file that was opened:

```
from itertools import izip
with open("/etc/passwd") as a, open("/etc/group") as b, open("/etc/shadow") as c:
    for lines in izip(a,b,c):
        print map(lambda x: x.split(':')[0], lines)
```

Run this example twice; once as a root and once as normal user. Presuming you save this file as `ziptogether.py` first try invoking it as root with `sudo python ziptogether.py` and it will succeed, but invoking it as a normal user with `python ziptogether.py` will fail because you don't have permissions to read `/etc/shadow`. When it fails the context manager will ensure that the files that were successfully opened before the failure are properly closed when execution moves outside the scope of the `with` statement.

Comment: @NeuronQ I updated my answer to note that `nested()` is deprecated and there is an even simpler syntactic form for multiple context managers.

Answer (score 7):

You mention it already: It is cleaner to do

```
f = file(...)
try:
    # do work on file
finally:
    f.close()
```

than just closing after the file operations - which would not be reached if an exception occurs.

If you compare the `try/finally` to `with`, you have  the same level of indentation, so you don't lose anything. If, however, you do exception handling, you have one more level of indentation, which is indeed against the said Zen point.

OTOH, `with` encapsulates things and makes using them easier and more readable, which are other Zen aspects.

It seems impossible to me to always follow every Zen aspect exactly; sometimes you have to weigh one against the other. In this case, you "lose" one level of indentation, but you get a better readability and maintainability. The latter seems to be an advantage to me.

Comment: I tried to answer you but couldn't find a way to write code in the comments so I added my answer to you to the bottom of my question

Comment: I agree: Elements of the Zen of Python frequently need to be traded off against one another. In the present case I would argue that the one level of nesting that you must invest allows you to follow **Explicit is better than implicit**: When you see a `with`, it is explicit the end handling will occur (rather than depending on the logic's execution fate). "Explicit is better than implicit" is number 2 on the Zen of Python list and so *ought to* often trump less nesting. All is well.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the Zen of Python also says:

> Simple is better than complex.
>
> Complex is better than complicated.

and

> Readability counts.

Using a context manager in the `with` statement provides multiple things:

- correct behaviour as the file is always closed
- readability (`with open(..) as f` is quite understandable)

You can't point at one item in the Zen of Python and argue that all Python code must satisfy all items at all times. For example, if the minimum indentation level to solve a particular problem in a readable and correct way is four, then so be it: if an indentation level of three makes the code less readable then just leave the code alone (four is good).

Comment: What you say is very, very general... You are right on the "enforcing the correct behavior" point, as this would be good for quick hacky code, but I found that exactly the people that write "quick hacky  code" don't use the with statement. And the readability part is subjective (I find one more indentation level less readable, and when you do a "multiple files with" like "with open(...) as file1, open(...) as file3, open(...) as file4:" it ends up very unreadable because you have to scroll horizontally or ugly because you split the with statement on multiple line.

Comment: Is there a good reason for four files to be open at the same time? Usually I can read the data from the input files sequentially and the same for writing the data to one or more output files. Although I can imagine there to be situations where four files are needed.

Comment: @NeuronQ:  I can see nothing uggly on breaking the command on more lines, especialy when the `open(...) as fX` parts are aligned.  I agree with Simeon it is not the typical case.  Anyway, it is readable the same way as if the four consequent `fX = open(...)` commands were used.

Comment: Imagine parsing a bunch of corrupted data files and comparing compiling the data in them into one salvaged data file. Definitely not something anyone would enjoy doing, but it's what I'm doing right now. Yes, it could be done by processing everything sequentially, but when you have to do calls to a web API in the process of verifying data and some other ugly constraints it's just better to do it this way.

Comment: @pepr Indeed "ugly" is very subjective. It's the same as when you see some people's indentation style in something like Javascript or PHP and you just want to cut them into pieces with a chainsaw :)

Comment: @NeuronQ: If you insist on having a set of file object that should be open at once, you can wrap them to a dedicated container that treats them as one set, and that acts as the context manager for the set.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I have [update my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376817/462302) with an example of when you might want to open multiple files using a `with` statement such as when you want to zip together multiple lines of a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Flat is better than nested"
```

Well, what is **flat**?

```
import thirdparty
print "I Like Pie!"
```

vs

```
import org.example.thirdparty.something
System.out.println("I Like Cake")
```

etc...

The Zen of Python does not simply enforce an indentation limit on your code. It encourages you to write readable (and thus, better) code.
If your `with` statement is in a function which is only accessible by 3 layers of objects (etc, `one.two.three.func()`), Then it's a problem.

Otherwise, three indention levels are just as good a number as any.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to prefer the `with` is that you do not need to pair *manually* the related operations (like `open(...)`/`.close()`; but the `with` construct is more general -- not only for working with files).  This is important namely in cases when the second operation may not be executed because of the reasons that are not clearly visible from the source code.  You are telling the machine *take care of it for me*, and the machine is better in the case than human.  This way you get rid the group of nasty errors that may be difficult to find.

By the way, you should use `open(...)` instead of the `file(...)`.  Python 3 knows nothing about the `file(...)` and you will otherwise have to fix your code later.

Comment: Indeed, maybe I should explore the use of `with` with other things than files, I never really gave this a good thought. Yeah, `open(...)` it's what I use, I don't know where my mind was when I wrote `file(...)` but fortunately it didn't affect the meaning of the question.